# If $G$ be a $d$-generator abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$ and exponent $p^e$, then is $e\geq n/d$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a $d$-generator abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$ and exponent $p^e$. Does $d$ divide $n$? Is is true that $e\geq n/d$?

I was wondering if someone help me about my problem. Thanks in advance.

What I've tried: Since $G$ is a $d$-generator abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$, $G\cong C_{p^{n_1}}\times \cdots \times C_{p^{n_d}}$ by classification of finite abelian groups. On the other hand, $p^{n_i}\leq p^e$ for every $1\leq i\leq d$ by the hypothesis. So $p^n=p^{n_1}\ldots p^{n_d}\leq p^e \ldots p^e=p^{de}$ hence $n\leq de$.

Is my proof true? Does $d$ divide $n$?

Comment: Well, isn't the number of generators of $G^{ab}$ not greater than $d$? And then it follows just from classification of finite abelian groups.

Comment: You say that $G$ has order $p^n$ but then never mention $n$ again. What is $p$? Is it supposed to be a prime number?

Comment: @radekzak The number of generators of $G^{ab}$ is equal to $d$ since $G$ is a finite $p$-group. How can I derive it from classification of finite abelian groups?

Comment: @DerekHolt You're right. Yes, actually $G$ is a finite $p$-group.

Comment: But clearly $n=3$, $d=2$ is possible, e.g. $G = C_{p^2} \times C_p$.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ableian groups". Please take the time to clean up such obvious errors before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof that $n\leq de$ is essentially correct, but this does not imply that $d$ divides $n$ (why would it), and in fact, $d$ does not necessarily divide $n$, consider for example $C_{p^2}\times C_p$, as in the comments.

Comment: You're right. I got it. Thank you very much.